# Отмена перехода по странице меню Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы нажимаю на пункт меню переход на страницу не осуществлялся бы?

Comment: Переход по клику на ссылку?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(selector).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ........................
});
```

Comment: А как мне поможет данный скрипт? Если меню на php формируется автоматически?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте скрипт на jQuery с обработкой события кликов по пунктам меню (можно прямо в теге `<script>` сразу после вывода меню).
Для меню, где класс пунктов списка дефолтный (`menu-item`) будет что-то вроде:

```
jQuery('.menu-item a').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Обновление**

Решение на конкретном примере (предполагается, что библиотека jQuery уже подключена)

```
<?php
$menu_params = array(
    'menu' => 'main_menu' /* указываем класс меню */
);
wp_nav_menu($menu_params); /* выводим меню */
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.main_menu a').on('click', function(e){ //следим за кликами по всем ссылкам из меню с классом "main_menu"
        e.preventDefault(); //отменяем переход по ссылке, на которую кликнул пользователь
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Это не то, что нужно @@alenkins

Comment: Тогда уточните вопрос. Как я понимаю, вам необходимо отменять переход по ссылке из меню сайта, когда пользователь по ней кликает.

Comment: Правильно понимаете, только проблема в том, что вы заранее не знаете количество пунктов в меню и следовательно ваш код не применим

Comment: Нет необходимости знать количество пунктов меню заранее. Событие вешается на все элементы с подходящим классом.

Comment: Вы не понимаете, прочитайте задачу заново

Comment: @ChromeChrome, поясните, почему этот ответ не решает вашу задачу?